# export Qt function to Tcl

Tags: qt, tcl, swig

What is the best way to export the code written in Qt to the script language TCL. In the code Qt, I use the data structure in Qt like QMAP, QLIST other than those in STL, so the SWIG may not recognize them and neither some other macros in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

You need a linking function with this signature:

```
extern "C" int theFunctionName(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp,
                               int argc, char **argv)
```

which you register with `Tcl_CreateCommand`. (Or there's `Tcl_CreateObjCommand`, which uses a more efficient type management system, but in principle it's pretty similar.) This is what SWIG would construct for you, with *lots* of guidance, but it's not too hard to DIY and you'll probably end up with a better interface anyway. (SWIG's handling of enumerations and bit-sets is usually very unidiomatic from a Tcl perspective.)

That linking function has to decide the values in `argv` to create the values that are passed to your Qt/C++ code, and then it uses `Tcl_SetResult` or `Tcl_SetObjResult` to store the result back in the `Tcl_Interp` context before returning `TCL_OK` or `TCL_ERROR` (for success or an exception).

I guess a QMap would look like a Tcl dictionary, and a QList like a Tcl list, but the details could get quite tricky. The details depend on exactly what's going on (stuff like callbacks gets a little tricky, especially in threaded code!)